# Display an array 'in order'?

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array called **$rank_array**:
`Array ( [Tribus Bella] => 179 ) Array ( [TestClan] => 767 )`

When I run this code:

```
foreach ($rank_array as $clan => $rank) {
    echo $clan.' = '.$rank.'<br />';
}
```

I get the following:

```
Tribus Bella = 179
TestClan = 767
```

I'd like to display it in the reverse order (so the it's ordered by the $rank variable), but when I use something like **asort** it doesn't change the order at all.
Can anyone help explain why? And help me fix it?

**edit**
None of the functions seem to be working (arsort, asort, etc) so I'm wondering if it's the way I'm inserting the data into the array.
I'm inserting it with this code

```
$rank_array = array($q['name'] => $clan_total_points);
```

Is that wrong?

Comment: if your array is already ordered by the appropriate attribute why dont u just output it in reverse order (you can use array_reverse for that)?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working either. Nothing seems to be reversing it. Just as a side note, the array won't necessarily be in order so I reckon a sort would be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more-to-less value sorting use [arsort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) function.

Comment: None of the sorting functions I've found or been told about seem to be working. I reckon it's the way I'm inserting the data into the array. Could you take a look at my question again (I've posted an edit) to check the way I'm inserting it?

Answer (score 5):

<strike>The default sort flag for `asort()` is `SORT_REGULAR`, which will sort in **ascending** order - which the order in which they already are. You need to sort into **descending** order, which you would do like this:</strike>

```
asort($rank_array, SORT_DESC);
```

Now when you loop `$rank_array`, it will be in the order in which you want it. <sup>*Wrong!*</sup>

As @Nameless has correctly pointed out, the *correct* answer to this question is that you need to use [`arsort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) in order to achieve what you want.

Comment: I've just added that, but it still doesn't want to go. It displays it in the same order as it is now, no matter what I put in there

Comment: My humble apologies, the correct answer to this is what @Nameless has posted.

Comment: No sorting functions seem to be working. It must be the way I'm inserting the data into the array.

Comment: @RichardHedges `arsort()` definitely works for me - [see for yourself](http://codepad.org/4Lr7KTMH)

Comment: Sorry, it's the way I was putting the data into the array. I was creating a new array for each 'clan'.